# violin plots in ggplot 2 with Date on the X axis and dependent variable on the Y

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I'm trying to make a violin plot showing the number of insect visits to a plant variety for different dates of observation. I have 25 different plant types and 16 different sequential dates.

I keep getting caught up with errors such as :"Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied" despite (attempting) to properly format the date. Here's my code:

```
violin_date<-df, sep = ",", header = TRUE, row.names(1))

violin_date$Date
violin_date$Date <- as.Date.character(violin_date$Date, format = 
"%m/%d/%y", origin = 1)

violin_date[, 2:26] <- log(violin_date[2:26])
is.na(violin_date) <- do.call(cbind,lapply(violin_date, is.infinite))
violin_date[is.na(violin_date)] <- 0

violin_date_melt = melt(as.matrix(violin_date))

ggplot (violin_date) + labs(x="Cultivar",y="Date") + geom_violin(aes(x 
= variable, y = Date), trim = FALSE) + coord_flip()
```

My data header looks like this:

```
    Date      MTO       MY      MDO       MR       MF      LSR       LY        LC
1 2016-07-06 3.895948 2.379877 3.496892 3.825758 2.137259 0.000000 3.829630 4.467857
2 2016-07-07 0.000000 4.448635 2.955516 0.000000 3.275105 0.000000 0.000000 3.592755
3 2016-07-13 6.685971 5.180261 5.459738 6.297448 6.073368 8.222671 7.026091 0.000000
4 2016-07-21 5.327740 6.049159 6.408181 4.745223 6.451136 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
5 2016-07-25 5.671947 5.102823 4.998650 4.549558 5.604289 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
6 2016-07-26 5.685996 4.632958 6.095359 5.348789 5.006001 0.000000 0.000000 4.806940
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think the problem is coming from your `violin_date$Date <- as.Date.character` line. It looks like you're specifying the wrong format, which will produce NAs. What happens if you just use `violin_date$Date <- as.Date(violin_date$Date)` at that step?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can try.

1. use [readr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=readr) to import the data set.  From the looks of the data set you provided, `readr::read_delim` will automatically read in the dates in the correct storage mode.
2. Use [dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dplyr) and [tidyr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=tidyr) to modify the data set so that you can build the wanted violin plot.

Hear is an illustration:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)


# Local data example
data_file <-
"Date MTO MY MDO MR MF LSR LY LC
2016-07-06 3.895948 2.379877 3.496892 3.825758 2.137259 0.000000 3.829630 4.467857
2016-07-07 0.000000 4.448635 2.955516 0.000000 3.275105 0.000000 0.000000 3.592755
2016-07-13 6.685971 5.180261 5.459738 6.297448 6.073368 8.222671 7.026091 0.000000
2016-07-21 5.327740 6.049159 6.408181 4.745223 6.451136 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
2016-07-25 5.671947 5.102823 4.998650 4.549558 5.604289 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
2016-07-26 5.685996 4.632958 6.095359 5.348789 5.006001 0.000000 0.000000 4.806940
"

# Use readr::read_delim to read in the data set.  You can explicity define the
# colume types via col_types, but the data is well formated and the default
# guesses will work well.  Instead of the `data_file` used in this example,
# you'll want to use the path to the actual data file.
violin_data <- read_delim(data_file, delim = " ")
str(violin_data, max.level = 1)

# Use tidyr::gather instead of reshape2::melt
violin_data <- gather(violin_data, key = variable, value = value, -Date)
str(violin_data)

# create a weight variable for each variable.  dplyr will make this easy.
violin_data <-
  violin_data %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  mutate(wt = value / sum(value)) %>%
  ungroup()

# build the plot
ggplot(violin_data) +
  aes(x = variable, y = Date, weight = wt) +
  geom_violin()
```

[image]